# How to send custom get request using Odata4j

Tags: odata, odata4j

I want to send following `GET` request using `Odata4j`

```
http://**.**.***.***:****/sap/opu/odata/sap/
                                         MOBILE_SERVICES/EmpPernrs
                                               (name='abc',lastName='xyz')
```

can anybody tell me how to send such request to OData server using OData4j consumer object.

I have created consumer object like:

```
ODataConsumer.Builder builder = ODataConsumers
                    .newBuilder("http://**.**.***.***:****/sap/opu
                    /odata/sap/MOBILE_SERVICES/");
builder.setClientBehaviors(authenticationBehavior);
consumer = builder.build();
```